# Why is the power consumption of electrical lamps specified in kWh/1000h?

Tags: power, watts, lightning

This is the box of a LED spot I just bought. I'm wondering why the power consumption is measured in kWh/1000h and not simply in Watts.

[image: Photograph of box]

**Edit:**

The labeling standard can be found [here](http://www.lightingeurope.org/uploads/files/LightingEurope_Guide_-_Regulation_874_2012_ENERGY_LABELLING__Version_1_23_May_2013.pdf). (Guide for the application of the commision regulation (EU) No. 874/2012 with regard to energy labelling of electrical lamps and luminaries).

Comment: Because they think you're a dumb consumer.

Comment: There are no other technical details on the box?

Comment: I wonder where I can find "The Commission Regulation (EU) No. 874/2012 states in Annex VII, part 2.", No Annex VII in the document.

Comment: Do ah look like ah know what a killer what is?

Comment: Monthly electricity bills are in terms of kWh (e.g. $0.30/kWh), so a consumer can easily see the cost of running this light bulb in terms of money per hour (in this case 7*0.03 cents per hour).

Comment: 1000h is probably close to how long the lamp in the living room is on in a year.

Comment: 1000 h is [average life expectancy of a light bulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoebus_cartel).

Comment: Ironically, this abbreviation is longer than spelling `Watts` in full.

Comment: @TrangOul I bet it's not true for LED lamps anymore.

Comment: As an aside, LEDs in the US do just use W, for the most part (usually with a note somewhere about the equivalent wattage for an incandescent bulb). The actual brightness does seem to be most commonly given in lumens now, however.

Comment: @JAB: What you're thinking of is the packaging front; it's carrying basically the same information in Europe as well. [See here](http://fastvoice.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Osram-A40-6W-Pressebild.jpg) -- you see "6W = 40W" with appropriate imagery on the packaging front (top-right), and below that the (more accurate) "470 lm". What the OP is talking about is the EU energy label on the right side of the package, which is standardized for *any* kind of electrical appliance. As Philipp stated, the different unit given is probably because `kWh` is what you pay for.

Comment: By the way: This [LED bulb from IKEA](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/40288066/) consumes 3.5W. Or 4kWh/1000h. (It's just an example, you'll find this very often) This so-called energy label should tell the "dumb" consumer how much power a device needs. That average value is nice for fridges, but it fails for such low-power devices, as it tells him it needs 14% more than it actually does. [Another example showing it's not just due to rounding](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/10266221/)

Comment: Another strange thing: The upper right symbols means "Don't throw it into the residual waste bin". The lower right means "Throw it into the recycling bin". While the upper addresses the bulb, the lower addresses the packaging... tztztz

Comment: @sweber And then there's the 30-degree right angle. DevSolar: I see.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Anyone who has a clue about how physical units works will of course realize that `kWh/1000h` means "1000 watt-hours per 1000 hours" which can be shortened to just `W`.

But when it comes to lamps, the unit "W" is already used for the light output. Light bulbs which use more energy-efficient technologies than the classical incandescent light bulb often state their light output in equivalency to an incandescent bulb with a specific power consumption. Until 2010 you could often find LED light bulbs stating to be "equivalent to a 40W bulb". So the consumer knows that if they want to replace an old 40W incandescent bulb with an equally bright LED bulb, they need to look for a 40W LED bulb. A consumer buying an LED lamp with an *input* power of 40W might be surprised by how bright it is.

Also, the average consumer doesn't know much about how electricity works. They know they need to pay for their electricity consumption in a unit called "kWh", so they want to know how much they need to pay when they run the device for x hours.

So from the point of view of the average consumer, the unit "Watt" means "light-intensity" and "kWh per hour" means "energy consumption". A physicist will of course inject that the unit for visible light radiated by a source is "Lumen" and "Watt" is the unit energy consumption should be measured in, so that's what should be printed on light bulb boxes. But physicists aren't average consumers.

Using different units for each - even if both of them are misleading from a physicist's point of view - is what's the least misleading way to communicate it to the end-user.

Comment: That's the "least misleading" until marketing people figure out a light bulb is lit 4 hours a day on average, and invent a new clever unit 1`kWh/year`==0.68`kWh/1000h`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev ...and then there is a lawsuit and they need to add a fine-print *Yearly consumption may vary depending on how you use your light bulb. And then another marketing company comes along and realizes they can make their exactly identical product look better when they manage to find a study which says a bulb is only lit about 3 hours a day.

Comment: @Philipp They can always start the fine print with "Does not contain asbestos. No animals were hurt during production..." so everyone stops reading before the sentence you mentioned comes up. So yeah, in the end that second company wins.

Comment: People, please, stop giving them ideas...

Comment: To be fair, most light bulb packaging that I've seen *does* include lumen ratings, it's just buried in the fine, light print at the bottom.

Comment: @mikołak I think you might be too late.  In the US light bulb lifespan is already measured using 1 year = 1000 hours (2.8 hours/day); and AFAIK the "you'll save $NN a year" (vs incandescent bulbs) marking on CFL/LED packages is based off that usage number.

Comment: @DanNeely ?? But "you'll save $NN per year" would also depend on something as volatile as local energy prices

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah, I've always rolled my eyes over that over simplification.  I believe the fine print says that they use the national average price of [12c/KWh](http://www.npr.org/sections/money/2011/10/27/141766341/the-price-of-electricity-in-your-state); which isn't too far off (50% high to 33% low) if you exclude Hawaii as an extreme outlier.

Comment: Even though (as stated) most folk don't understand electricity, somehow thy came to understand how bright 40W was. Surely, if the brightness was given in lumens, folk would get used to that terminology, even though most folk don't understand light?

Comment: Sadly, this is exactly the kind of confused thinking that in my opinion is the cause (as opposed to a consequence) of people not understanding physics. It should be mandatory to display lumens for light output and watts for consumed power and ban all other units. But then again, I am a physicist.

Answer (score 17):

The energy rating covers all types of electrical appliances including fridges, washing machines, etc.

In the case of a fridge the instantaneous current could be zero or full on depending on the thermostat. It makes more sense to put the fridge into a 20°C room, power it up and read the kWh used in, say, 24 h and scale it up. This gives a better idea of the average power consumed by the device.

I agree that this could be quoted as X watts average. On the other hand if I know I pay €0.15 / kWh for electrical energy it is a very simple calculation for a non-technical user to figure out the cost of running the appliance.

Mind your units: 'K' is kelvin. 'k' is kilo. ;^)

Comment: "On the other hand if I know I pay €0.15 / kWh for electrical energy it is a very simple calculation for a non-technical user to figure out the cost of running the appliance."  Is it?  Tell said non-technical user that it uses 7kWh/1000h and then ask them how much it'd cost a year.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Let's just hope that price drops to 0.12 €/kWh and then we can simply state 1 W = 1 €/year :)

Comment: @NPSF3000 Knowing the number of hours in a year is irrelevant. How many hours is the light bulb on per day? 1000 hours of use could equate to 10 years of minimal use. The fact is that *everything* is rated 'over 1000 hours' and is therefore directly comparable to *everything else*.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just a coincidence, but the nominal lifespan of a traditional incandescent filament lamp is 1000 hours.  So the kWh/1000h figure for an incandescent lamp is also the amount of power it would use over its lifespan.

Comment: "1000 hours of use could equate to 10 years of minimal use."  It could also be 1 year or 100 years, as an average non-technical user, how do I figure this out?

Comment: The system is really intended as a simple energy efficiency comparison guide. You compare ratings while in the store and you can select between various appliances based on, amongst other things, their energy rating. A++ is best. E is worst. How many hours a year you run it, if at all, is your business.

Comment: You make it sound like `kWh/1000h` has the notion of average, while `W` does not, but they are **exactly the same**. If your light bulb lasted for 999 hours, or 1 hour, or minute, you can still choose to rate it in `kWh/1000h`.

Comment: So a year is 1000 hours? I thought it was pi E 7 seconds ...

Answer (score -1):

It allows you to do an easy comparison between different light bulbs, because it is a standardised way of presenting the power consumption of the item.